# Translation (en–de): Stack Overflow

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I would like to translate the Term **Stack Overflow**.

[Google](https://translate.google.de/?q=get%20you%20past&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla%3ade%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=de&sa=N&tab=wT#en/de/stack) gives me the following translation proposals for the term *stack*:

**Stapel**      -  stack, pile, batch, staple, stocks
**Paket**       -  package, packet, parcel, bundle
**Schornstein** -  chimney, stack, funnel, smokestack
**Haufen**      -  heap, pile, bunch, cluster, lot, crowd
**Pack**        -  pack, stack, bundle, rabble, bale, riffraff
**Magazin**     -  magazine, journal, mag, repository, storeroom, stockroom
**Stoß**        -  shock, impact, kick, push, joint, stack
**Packen**      -  pack, packing, package, bundle, stack, heap
**Felssäure**   -  stack

The context: I am looking for a appropriate translation for *Stack Overflow*.
**What is meant???**

An overflowing **Stapel or Haufen**,
an overflowing **Schornstein** or
an overflowing **Magazin**? (*this is what I guess*)

Comment: It's a technical term derived from software development and the German technical term is "Stapelüberlauf". That's where  the site has it's name from, it's a dev site.

Comment: A developer site... O.K. Thanx a lot!!! :-D

Comment: stackoverlow.com, yes, it's obviously a developer Q&A site, it's the one I use most. It is the original site from which stackexchange and the other sites like this one here started

Comment: I know. I am writing my Magister Thesis about gamification and that for I need to know every little bit about this sites. Only thing that bothers me, is that I don't have clue about programming... Greetz vom Germany. :-D

Comment: Greetz from Deutscheland, as well. Wenn du wissen willst, was ein Stapelüberlauf ist, kannst du das hier nachlesen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow Aber was hat stackoverflow mit gamification zu tun? Ich weiß, das gehört nicht in die comments, das sollte im Chat geklärt werden.

Comment: Wahrscheinlich meinst du das Belohnungs- und Anreizsystem, das die systematische Preisgabe und Versammlung von kollektivem Wissen ermöglicht.

Comment: _Lass uns mal English bleiben. Der Fairness halber..._ I Actually don't have the reputation to chat, at least I think so. How **Stack Overflow** and **Gamification** are related??? It is one of the **most mentionned (positive) examples** for using game mechanics in a non-gaming context. Points, badges, leaderboards, restrictions, privileges, progess bar, competition (who is best informed, who answers fastest... a.s.o. a.s.o.) This platform is gamification at it's best!!! Could be better, though... ;-)

Comment: Was ist jetzt eigentlich genau deine Frage? Willst du nur den Term "Stack Overflow" übersetzt bekommen? Warum hast du nicht mal nach "Stack overflow deutsch" gegoogelt: http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/stack+overflow.html

Comment: Sorry, I think this was too easy. My brain is a bit toasted. My fault. Thx!!!

Comment: An overflowing Haufen. This question is very funny

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Someone asks a question and it's put on a stack, another one asks the next question and it's also put on a stack, the next one asks and the stack grows and grows and grows. This is what happens here in this Q&A world.

A computer program usually calls subroutines which call subroutines which also call subroutines and so on. All local variables of a currently running routine are saved (pushed) on stack before a subroutine is called. This stack is a limited memory block, usually enough for a lot of subroutine calls, also since after a while the subroutine calls finish and the program returns to their appropriate caller routine and pops the saved variables from stack to continue the caller routine. But when there is too much to be saved on stack or too many subroutines are called, that memory usage will overflow and continuing writing new variables to stack corrupts neighboring memory parts and often causes program crashes. So a stack overflow is a well-known sort of bug for programmers.

That Q&A (question and answer) corner called "StackOverflow" is for programmers, and the wordplay was a nice one to keep the site in mind.

I'm not sure if all other Q&A corners, including this one, are added later, and that's why StackOverflow is the word often associated with the whole StackExchange server.

Comment: @DonDio You still can set this answer to your "accepted answer" to show that this is what you were looking for.

Comment: @Em1 Worked. Thanx for the advice. :-D

Answer (score 2):

Translation:

**[Stack Overflow](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow) - [Pufferüberlauf](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puffer%C3%BCberlauf)**  (equivalent: [Stapelüberlauf](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stapel%C3%BCberlauf))
Links to Wikipedia (german)

The term describes the following bug:

A progarm saves local variables (data) of a currently running routine or subroutine on a certain memory ([buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer)), if these (sub)routines generate more data, than the buffer is able to save, previously data will be overwritten.

Comment: Auf Deutsch aber "Puffer", oder? Und angesichts der Tatsache, dass oft sorgsam zwischen Stack und Heap unterschieden wird, ist 'certain memory' recht schwammig.

Comment: Note that a stack is a special buffer where new data is allways appended, and retrieved vice versa (LIFO=last in first out). But buffer memory is not always a stack.

Comment: This answer is as general and unspecific as possible, because I dont have the certain knowledge to give a specific answer. Feel free to edit!!! I am **not** a programmer. I study media science and write my magister thesis about gamification as a new form of user engagement. I am involving with this site, because I want to know what I'm writing about...

Comment: @userunknown: Deine Reputation reicht durchaus aus, um solche Fehler selbst zu korrigieren.

Comment: Das merkst Du früh! :) Es ist aber Geschmackssache, ob man Pufferüberlauf oder Bufferüberlauf sagt. Letzteres habe ich auch schon gehört, so dass mir unklar war, ob Du mit solch einer Änderung einverständen wärst. Nach reiflicher Überlegung offenbar schon. :)